# What is the difference between sklearn IsolationForests score_samples and decision_function?

Tags: scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

The predict method will output -1 (anomaly) where

`forest.decision_function(X) < forest.threshold_`

and 1 otherwise.

But what does `forest.score_samples(X)` gives me?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of the attribute `offset_`: we have that
`decision_function = score_samples - offset_`;

`score_samples` is more directly from the original paper, whereas the decision function desires the decision cutoff to be zero.